# Issue with basename

Tags: c++11, posix

So I am having an issue using basename for one of my programming assignments for school

I have tried getting a simplier version of it working -- I got it working however, still confused exactly what I am supposed to do in this case

```
// $Id: util.cpp,v 1.1 2016-06-14 18:19:17-07 - - $
#include <libgen.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

#include "util.h"

ydc_exn::ydc_exn (const string& what): runtime_error (what) {
}

string exec::execname_; // Must be initialized from main().
int exec::status_ = EXIT_SUCCESS;

void exec::execname (const string& argv0) {
   execname_ = basename (argv0.c_str());
   cout << boolalpha;
   cerr << boolalpha;
   DEBUGF ('Y', "execname = " << execname_);
}

void exec::status (int new_status) {
   new_status &= 0xFF;
   if (status_ < new_status) status_ = new_status;
}

ostream& note() {
   return cerr << exec::execname() << ": ";
}

ostream& error() {
   exec::status (EXIT_FAILURE);
   return note();
}
```

Just trying to get the code to compile --- my error message in c++ is:

```
' 
util.cpp:15:16: error: no matching function for call to 'basename'
   execname_ = basename (argv0.c_str());
               ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/libgen.h:40:7: note: candidate function not viable: 1st argument ('const std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>
      >::value_type *' (aka 'const char *')) would lose const qualifier
char    *basename(char *);
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [util.o] Error 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

`basename` takes `char*` as argument, which is not `const`, meaning the function is allowed to modify the value.

`const string& argv0` is `const`, meaning the value of `argv0` must not be modified.

Thus you are not allowed to call `basename` with `argv0.c_str()` as parameter, as that would violate the `const` qualifier.

The error message is clear: `1st argument ... would lose const qualifier`.

<s>So either change `argv0` to not be `const` (probably not a good idea), or change `basename` to take a `const char*` parameter (probably the better idea), or change `basename` to work with `std::string` instead of `char*` like the rest of your code (probably the best idea).</s>

So apparently `basename` is a unix function that you cannot change. (Thanks Nevin!) From the manpage:

> Both dirname() and basename() may modify the contents of  path,  so  it may be desirable to pass a copy when calling one of these functions.

In that case I recommend creating a copy of `argv0`. The simplest way of doing this would be to change the signature of `execname` to this:

```
void exec::execname(std::string argv0)
```

Comment: The OP can't change the signature of `basename(char*)` as it comes from Unix.

Comment: @Nevin ah, good to know. could you add an appropriate tag to the question? i wasn't aware OP is using OS specific functions. thanks!

Comment: @MaxVollmer it's Posix, not OS-specific (yes, I'm aware that's niggly....)

Comment: Unfortunately, because this is C++11, just passing argv0 by value doesn't solve the problem, as `.c_str()` is a const member function (and `string` doesn't get a non-const `.data()` member until C++17).  You can't necessarily dereference *begin() either, because the string might be empty.  For C++11, the code needs to be written like (adding a return value as it is used in `note()`):  ```std::string execname(const std::string& argv0)
{                                      
    std::vector<char> vpath(path.begin(), path.end() + 1); 
    return std::string(basename(vpath.data()));
}```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your central problem is including `libgen.h` as well as `cstring`. If you look at the prototypes for `basename` in those files, they're different. If you're building this on linux, you'll see a comment in the `libgen.h` version which should be enlightening.

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/basename.html and
https://linux.die.net/man/3/basename are useful here too.

I suggest *removing* the `#include <libgen.h>` and trying again.